# Capturing site search parameters from the URL hash in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, url, site-search

We want to capture aggregated, anonymous search query history for analytic purposes to improve our internal search engine performance and metadata practices.

I found this article: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en

Unfortunately, our search engine uses a hash tag instead of a question mark (nonstandard query string).

For example: `http://www.example.com/search#q=search%20term`

Is there a way to configure Google Analytics to recognize hash tag values in the URLs and capture these given a defined pattern?

Comment: Hi @user33769, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain about the # aspect but under the admin settings find the "track internal site search" setting and enable it. It won't allow you to enable it without including the query parameters and I assume you can just specify them there (up to 5).

I believe this is true in `ga.js` and `analytics.js` (aka 'Universal Analytics' which is now in public beta...for sure it is in Universal, but I think it's in `ga.js` as well)